# Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP - after activating CDN Railgun (IONOS)

Tags: google-chrome, cdn, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

After activating the *CDN (Railgun)* of my webhost (*IONOS*) i can't access PageSpeed Insights.

Error:

> "Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. Beim Aufzeichnen des Trace über
>   Ihren Seitenaufbau ist ein Problem aufgetreten."

Whats wrong? Audit still working fine.

Comment: Care to share your website URL and I can have a look for you? Unfortunately the error messages you get from Lighthouse are not the best for diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks for your offer. After some phone adventures with the support of my host, they fixed it, but didn't tell what was wrong.